# how print f1-score with scikit´s accuracy_score or accuracy of confusion_matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, accuracy, f1score

I would like to print the f1-score. I got confused about the wording f1-accuracy score and accuracy score. What is the difference of these 2 scikit-learn metrics and how can I print the f1-score out of this code?

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read...path
X = df.drop('pricing_class', axis=1)
y = df.pricing_class

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

xgb_classification = XGBClassifier(random_state=42)
xgb_classification.fit(X_train,y_train)

xgb_results=xgb_classification.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(xgb_results,y_test))
print('accuracy_score',accuracy_score(xgb_results, y_test))
```

this is a test sample:

[image]

Question 1:
There is under the column f1-score the row of accuracy. Is this the f1-score of the scikit-learn classification report? or is this the accuracy score?

I have the feeling, that this value is the rounded value of the accuracy_score the line below (when I use full dataset).

Question 2:
How can I print the f1-score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f1_score` instead of the classification report:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

...

print('f1_score', f1_score(xgb_results, y_test))
```

Comment: thanks this leads to my next question. I will make a new post. if it is possible to compare f1 'micro' out of models which are imbalanced, and not imbalanced because of smote.